# force to receive as argument of a method a superclass pointers that implements an interface

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a superclass A and several children classes (B, C, D...) some of these classes are also superclasses, so the relationship of these classes is a little bit complex.

Now I have introduced an interface class I with several pure virtual methods. This interface is implemented in different subclasses of A

```
class A { };

class I { };

class B : public A, public I { };

class C : public A { };

class D : public C, public I { };
```

I would want to call a function that receives as argument an A pointer, since the function uses the functionality og the A superclass. But the function expect that this argument also implements the interface. In the example above, the function should accept only B and D types

I am checking with a dynamic cast if this arg is a pointer of I

```
void f(A *obj)
{
    I *interface = dynamic_cast <I *>(obj);
    if (interface) ...
}
```

but I want to know if c++ allows me a better solution and check this at compiler time.

Thanks

Comment: You may consider redesigning the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enforce a compile-time restriction that both `A` and `I` are base classes of whatever pointer you pass in, you can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and  [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<A, T>::value && std::is_base_of<I, T>::value
>::type foo(T* t) {

}
```

`foo` will only be in the overload resolution set if `t` points to a class that inherits from both `A` and `I`. Whether this is a good solution for you or not depends of whether or not you want to allow something like:

```
A* a = new B;
foo(a); // it *is* a B, but will fail to instantiate the call
        // because I is not a base of A
```

Note that `is_base_of` allows for `A` to be a `private` base of `T`. If you want to enforce that it is an accessible base, you could instead use [`std::is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<T*, A*>::value && 
    std::is_convertible<T*, I*>::value
>::type foo(T* t) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt know this feature of c++. However it seems complex for me. Since its not possible redesign all the classes because there are a huge number of classes in my application. I would use delegates thats implements the interface. The delegate should be sendvas a second parameter of the method. So the call would have the first and second argument pointing to the same object. I know tgat this solution is not elegant. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value && std::is_base_of<I, T>::value>::type >
void foo(T* t) 
{

}
```

You could write a good alias:

```
template<typename D, typename B1, typename B2>
using extends = typename std::enable_of<std::is_base_of<B1,D>::value and std::is_base_of<B2,D>::value>::type;
```

so that you could write `foo` as:

```
template<typename T, typename = extends<T,A,I>> //T extends A and I.
void foo()
{
}
```

That looks a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

If `A` is a non-polymorphic type, `dynamic_cast` from `A*` to `I*` won't compile. Besides, since you are using dynamic dispatch, I would reckon that the dynamic type of `obj` is not known until runtime. So, you are probably heading in the wrong direction. Instead of what your are trying to do in the OP, redesigning the class hierarchy may actually be the right solution to your problem. An illustration:

```
class InterfaceOfA;
class I;
class AI: public InterfaceOfA, public I;
class A: public InterfaceOfA;
class B : public AI;
class C : public A;
class D : public C, public AI;
void f(AI *obj);
```